# Convert month number to text presentation

Tags: java, date-format, localdate

```
   public String getDate() throws ParseException{

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("LL dd, yyyy");
        LocalDate date = getPublishDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev")).toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(date);

        String text = date.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(text);

        return text;
    }
```

Output:

```
2016-10-01
10 01, 2016
```

I want to print month in text presentation: October 01, 2016.

`getPublishDate` - getter of private field `Date publishDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd','yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
//output: "October 01,2016"
```